# Falla compatibilidad android estudio

Tags: android, android-studio, api, build.gradle

tengo un problema con mi aplicación.Actualmente lo programe en android marshmallow de api 23 y lo estaba corriendo en un dispositivo físico Moto G5 plus de api24 y funcionaba perfectamente, pero, intente probarlo en un Samsum j5 prime de api 23 y no funciono. Saliendo un error("La aplicación se detuvo") y cerrándose. La verdad soy nuevo en esto de la programación así que les agradecería que expliquen de una forma simple de entender .Gracias

Logcat:

```
09-16 16:58:22.185 13259-13259/? E/Zygote: v2
09-16 16:58:22.185 13259-13259/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
09-16 16:58:23.515 13259-13259/com.example.eliseo.radio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.eliseo.radio, PID: 13259
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eliseo.radio/com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:487)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400)
    at com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:487) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
    at com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:487) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
    at com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.eliseo.radio:drawable/fondo" (7f060055) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060055 a=-1 r=0x7f060055}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4249)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4156)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4006)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:487) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
    at com.example.eliseo.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.eliseo.radio"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

contenido carpeta drawable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según el logcat, el error se está produciendo al momento de realizar el Inflate de un ImageView. Especulando un poco, podría deberse a un findView perdido, para una respuesta más concreta se necesitaría visualizar el código en donde rellenas el inflate del layout de la MainActivity.

Comment: Esta línea: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.eliseo.radio:drawable/fondo" (7f060055) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060055 a=-1 r=0x7f060055}` hace pensar a que estás tratando de usar un recurso que no existe o que no es de ese tipo. No creo que sea cuestión de que funcione en un dispositivo y no en otro. Si pruebas **exactamente la misma acción en cualquier dispositivo** es muy probable que falle en todos. Sería conveniente que identifiques la línea del error y revises los recursos que usas ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no puede inflar el layout ya que en la linea 10 tiene definido un `ImageView` el cual no puede ser inflado:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10:
>   Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class
>   android.widget.ImageView

**la razón por la cual este `ImageView` tiene este problema es que estas tratando de cargar en el un recurso `drawable/fondo` el cual no es en realidad una imagen o el recurso no existe** :

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.example.eliseo.radio:drawable/fondo" (7f060055) is not a Drawable
>   (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060055 a=-1 r=0x7f060055}

**Comentas que en algunos dispositivos funciona y en otros no, esto puede ser debido a que agregaste el recurso solo en algún folder `/drawable-<API>` dedicado para una API y no en todos, en este caso puede encontrarse la imagen únicamente en `/drawable-24` pero no en `/drawable-23`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys♦, puede ser por que a la par de mis imágenes  tengo "(v24)" ?.Pero no  en el folder ,si no en el mismo  elemento.Lo dejo adjuntado arriba en el post. Y si fuera este el problema como lo podría solucionar ?